# SonarQube integration withn GCP cloud build

Tags: google-cloud-platform, sonarqube

I have a task to use SonarQube.

My build are done using Google Cloud Build. How can I integrate SonarQube with Google Cloud Build

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can use [custom builders](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/cloud-builders#writing_your_own_custom_builder). At the end, each build step is a container image:

> Cloud builders are container images with common languages and tools installed in them. You can configure Cloud Build to run a specific command within the context of these builders.

[There GCP documentation provides a guide on how to create a custom build](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configuring-builds/use-community-and-custom-builders#creating_a_custom_builder). However, notice that it's inteded to be general and doesn't include any specific functionality that you might require. Nevertheless, is a great starting point for understanding how the custom builders work and create your own.

Aside from this approach, [there is a community builder for Sonarqube](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community/tree/master/sonarqube) that you can use as reference or might even suit your needs.

*Edit*:

In case your question is about code analysis with Sonarqube. The community builder is still relevant as it allows you to [run static code analysis for your project](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community/tree/master/sonarqube#sonarqube-scanning) from `sonarcloud.io`.